# Query String with DatastoreService

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Using the `DatastoreService` how can I do queries for `String` containing some string similar to Java `String`:

- contains
- startsWith
- endsWith

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When querying against a String property, exact matches are the easiest, since that behavior works "out of the box".

"startsWith" queries can be done fairly easily by turning `property startsWith: abc` into `property >= 'abc' and property < 'abd'`, where you calculate the end of the range.

"endsWith" can be done by storing a reversed copy of the String, and creating a query as above, but with the target reversed. I.e., `property endsWith: 'abc'` becomes `propertyReversed >= 'cba' and propertyReversed < 'cbb'.

"contains" is a large challenge. There are several approaches, and the right one for your situation depends on your situation. If the string is relatively short (e.g., a name of an address), you could store list of trailing substrings, matching against them with a range query as above.

Answer (score 0):

As Dave mentions in his answer, `contains` is not available as a Datastore primitive. If you're looking for containment queries, the [Search API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/overview) is a good place to look (note: it's still in experimental).